# how to make a while loop for prizes in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, while-loop

Hi i want to make this code work, i have to print the list of prizes that eric won but i get error on this and i dont know how to continue

my code

```
#eric wishlist
eric,car,plane,jet
prize = read_txt("wishlist.txt")
        while prize:
            p = prize.pop(0)
            das = p.split(",")
            length = len(das)
            score = 0
            i = 1
            while i < 2:
                i += 1
                print(das)
```

so i pop the first to eliminate eric and want to print the first 2 prizes thar are car,plane but it dont work :( any help please.

Answer (score 0):

1. Fix your indentation. In Python it matters. The while block is indented too far right. You'll get an error telling you this.
2. You aren't including all the necessary components for us to troubleshoot your code. We don't know what `eric`, `car`, `plane`, `jet` are supposed to hold (and the way you have written them doesn't make sense in Python). Furthermore, we don't have the definition for the `read_txt` function, but we can assume it reads the file wishlist.txt. Also, if you're storing a data structure in that file, you will need to parse it, most commonly with the `json` package, or in your case it looks like they are separated by the delimiter `,` so you could just split the line into a list. I'm guessing your function does this. Don't pop before you split.

It could just be the indentation.